# Fastest way to transfer array to text file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a one dimensional array with more than 3 million items and I would like to transfer it to a text file. I tried a FileSystemObject method, which is not fast enough for me. So I tried to write to cells in a worksheet and export it as txt file, but I am still searching for a faster way to write an array to a txt file.

Comment: Show the code you are using

Comment: ... and please test all suggested answers and tell us, how fast FSO, FileStream and Put have been.

Comment: Both your solutions worked faster than my method. I think joining array before transfer increases the speed. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try also [Put](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/put-statement) (and maybe later also Get):

```
Private Sub TestPut(myArray() as string)
    Dim handle As Long
    handle = FreeFile
    Open Application.Defaultfilepath & "\Whatever.txt" For Binary As #handle
    Put #handle, , myArray
    Close #handle
End Sub
```

You may join your array as a single string to prevent unwanted descriptors (see above Put-documentation) and to define CR or CRLF or whatever as delimiter,
but only if the resulting string's length does not exceed 2,147,483,647 bytes:

```
Put #handle, , Join(myArray, vbCrLf)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that

```
FilePath = "C:\output.txt"
Set FileStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
FileStream.Open
FileStream.Type = 2 'Text
FileStream.Charset = "utf-8"
FileStream.WriteText vba.Strings.Join(YourArray)
FileStream.SaveToFile (FilePath)
FileStream.Close
```

Comment: nice code thank you! the only thing is the code does not finish normally if the file by FilePath already exists. if you can advice how to solve it please do. so far i think that one has to check in advance if the txt file already exists